# Trouble attaching file in postman for testing spring boot restapi

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, postman, multifile-uploader

I have written code for uploading file in spring boot , when I test it , I get status 200 ok , but the file is not getting uploaded . Can some one help me on this . Below is the code , I can see the sysout from the method in controller is being printed but after that the length is being printed as zero. I would further like to add that the uploadFile method is working i.e., the method which takes single file works as expected , but the method which is written to upload multiple files is not working as expected and I see the length of list of Multipart file is being printed as zero .

[Java Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDGJV.png)

postman test :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rw6f.png)

postman console :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzeRC.png)
postman console 2 :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrK5e.png)

[filestogeservice storefile method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxhBX.png)

Comment: Can you post your **fileStorage** service?

Comment: I pasted the file storefile method of filestorageservice

Comment: In postman you are calling **uploadMultipleFiles** . Try calling **uploadFile**

Comment: I would like to update that I was doing the testing wrong , in postman we need to add the key value as "files" which matches the parameter in the code, I was simply attching the files and clicking on submit which is not  actually sending the "files" parameter to the code and so the files were not getting uploaded.

Comment: Are you getting same result what you expecting?

Comment: yes @AvijitBarua .. thanks for looking into this ..